# The Lyapunov stability of zero solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am interseted in the stability of the zero solution of
\begin{equation}
\frac{dx}{dt}=-y-xy^2 \qquad \frac{dy}{dt}=x-x^4y
\end{equation}
Use Lyapunov function $V(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. And we have:
\begin{equation}
\frac{dV}{dt}=2x(-y-xy^2)+2y(x-x^4y)=-2x^2y^2-2x^4y^2=-2x^2y^2(1+x^2)\leq0
\end{equation}
So the zero solution is stable. 
Furthermore, I would like to confirm whether the zero solution is asymptotically stable. Specifically, the function $\frac{dV}{dt}=0$ iff $x=0$ or $y=0$. However, $x=0$ or $y=0$ are not the solution of the differential equation. So the zero solution should be asymptotically stable.

But by coding from wolframalpha, the steamplot shows the zero solution is stable but not asymptotically stable. I want to know what is wrong with my proof?

[image]

Comment: Your Lyapunov conditions shows that the system is stable but one cannot conclude on the asymptotic stability of the process. Are you trying to apply LaSalle's invariance principle for proving the asymptotic stability?

Comment: You can't determine stability or not from that streamplot. What makes you think that WA says it's not asymptotically stable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For small $x,y$ the perturbation to the circular system $\dot x=-y$, $\dot y=x$ is very small, so that the solution curves will look very circular. Averaging over the circle will give a better picture of this slow convergence. This is an approximation, not a complete proof.
So
$$
r\dot r=x\dot x+y\dot y=-r^4\sin^2\phi\cos^2\phi(1+r^2\cos^2\phi)
$$
gives
\begin{align}
\dot{\bar r}&=-\frac{\bar r^3}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac18\sin^2(2\phi)(2+\bar r^2(1+\cos(2\phi))\,d\phi
\\
&=-\frac{\bar r^3}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac1{16}(1-\cos(4\phi))(2+\bar r^2)\,d\phi
\\
&=-\frac1{16}\bar r^3(2+\bar r^2)
\end{align}
So for small $r$ this dynamic is approximately $\dot{\bar r}=-\frac18\bar r^3$, so that
$$
\bar r(t)=\frac{\bar r_0}{\sqrt{1+\frac14\bar r_0^2(t-t_0)}}.
$$

For the inner loop in the streamplot with the not so small $\bar r_0=0.8$ this gives after one turn
$$
\bar r(t_0+2\pi)=\frac{0.8}{\sqrt{1+0.32\pi}}=0.565
$$
which seems to fit.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Now  I know that I cannot use the steam plot to determine whether the zero solution is asymptotically stable or not. Thanks again!